# ASP.net MVC3 save last action when user navigates from site, redirect to that action when they return

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, session

Basically what I have is a site that uses Windows Live Connect for authentication.  When the user chooses to sign in from the master view, they are redirected to the WL sign in page obviously hosted elsewhere.  Once they have successfully signed in, they are redirected to a SignIn action on my site which potentially adds the user to my database if it is their first visit, sets up session variables, etc.

The issue right now though, is that I always have the SignIn action return a RedirectToAction to the main home page.  This will likely be annoying for a user since they now have to navigate back to whatever page it was they were needing to sign in to view.

My first thought was to add the following to my important actions to save the user's current place:

```
Session["LastPage"] = RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

Then at the end of my SignIn action I tried to include:

```
if (Session["LastPage"] != null)
    return (ActionResult)Session["LastPage"];
else
    return RedirectToAction("MyPage", "User");
```

This doesn't actually work though, since apparently my session is getting restarted every time the user navigates away from and back to the site.

Am I approaching this issue the right way?  If so, how do I keep the session from getting wiped?  If I'm going about this completely the wrong way, then can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can give a extra query string with your redirect link to the live authentication site.

Just add this query string:

**&redirect_uri=YOURURL**

You can get your previous URL with **Request.UrlReferrer**

Comment: The redirect uri supplied has to match what you have registered as your redirect uri in your app settings for win live.  So, this value has to always be the same.  Plus, it needs to redirect to my SignIn action no matter what anyway since that registers the user.  I just want to redirect to the last page from my sign in action.

Comment: In that case the Session method is the way to go. But I now see you are using the session wrong. You can't just put RedirectToAction in your session. That's why you are getting nulls when the users returns.  You will have to put the path in the session and then you should be able to get it.

Comment: Regardless, my session is being destroyed when I navigate away from the site, and when I return a new session is created.  This is why it is null.

Comment: That shouldn't happen unless your session timeout is very small. This is probably the cause http://weblogs.asp.net/bleroy/archive/2004/08/03/Don_2700_t-redirect-after-setting-a-Session-variable-_2800_or-do-it-right_2900_.aspx